# How to make an SVG object follow a path correctly using SMIL

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I am trying t create a simple SVG animation(using SMIL) and I can't seem to figure out why the orb isn't following the arc, instead the orb it is at the bottom of the page.
Here is my code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1240 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1240 768;" xml:space="preserve">


<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st1{fill:#0FBA70;}
</style>
<animateMotion xlink:href="#orb" dur="10s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
</animateMotion>
<g>
    <polygon class="st0" points="389.5,405.5 394,405.5 926.8,400.5 930.5,400.5  "/>
    <path id="motionPath" d="M390.9,407.5l-2.9-4.1C426,377,625,248.9,820.4,327.2c40.5,16.2,78.1,40.3,111.8,71.5l-3.4,3.7
        c-33.2-30.8-70.3-54.5-110.2-70.5C625.5,254.5,428.5,381.3,390.9,407.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle id="orb" class="st1" cx="389.5" cy="400.5" r="56.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orb is currently being offset with the `cx` and `cy` values:

```
<circle id="orb" class="st1" cx="389.5" cy="400.5" r="56.5"/>
```

If you remove those values, the orb follows the path:

```
<circle id="orb" class="st1" r="56.5"/>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion for a working example, and if you open that in JSFiddle or Codepen and add a `cx` or `cy` value you will observe the same behavior (circle is animating offset from the path).

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #0FBA70;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1240 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1240 768;" xml:space="preserve">
<animateMotion xlink:href="#orb" dur="10s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
</animateMotion>
<g>
    <polygon class="st0" points="389.5,405.5 394,405.5 926.8,400.5 930.5,400.5  "/>
    <path id="motionPath" d="M390.9,407.5l-2.9-4.1C426,377,625,248.9,820.4,327.2c40.5,16.2,78.1,40.3,111.8,71.5l-3.4,3.7
        c-33.2-30.8-70.3-54.5-110.2-70.5C625.5,254.5,428.5,381.3,390.9,407.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle id="orb" class="st1" r="56.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```